# Inputbox which will display only password charaters (like *) in vb.net

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I want the code for inputbox which will display only password characters like *. This will be written in a CLASS in vb.net. I am using VISUAL STUDIO 2008

Answer (score 0):

Is there something wrong with the [TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx) control and setting its [PasswordChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar.aspx) property to `*`? Or using [PasswordBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.passwordbox.aspx) if it is a WPF application that you are working on?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [TextBox.PasswordChar Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar.aspx)